# Decode nested variable-length JSON in ELM

Tags: javascript, json, decode, elm

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around decoding a bit complex JSON response in ELM. The JSON response structure(I have no control over it) doesn't match my application's data tree/model.

**What will the decoder code look like for this JSON ?**

I'm using *NoRedInk's Json.Decode.Pipeline* - http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/3.0.0/Json-Decode-Pipeline

My project's *Github repo* - https://github.com/areai51/my-india-elm

The *JSON* response - https://data.gov.in/node/85987/datastore/export/json

**Code**

```
 type alias Leader =
    { attendance : Float      <------- Logic = (Sessions Attended / Total Sessions) * 100
    , name : String
    , state : String
    }


type alias Model =
    { leaders : WebData (List Leader)
    }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { leaders = RemoteData.Loading
    }
```

**JSON**
*Note that there aren't keys I can directly map to inside the "data" array.*

```
{
   "fields":[   // Definitions for the "data" key
      {
         "id":"a",
         "label":"S.No.",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "id":"b",
         "label":"Division\/Seat No.",
         "type":"string"
      },....
    ],
   "data":[      <------- Leaders
      [
         1,
         3,
         "Smt.  Sonia  Gandhi",      <------- Name
         15,
         12,
         "Uttar Pradesh",      <------- State
         "Rae Barelii",
         20,      <------- Total Sessions (Attendance)
         9      <------- Sessions Attended (Attendance)
      ],
      [
         2,
         15,
         "Shri  Dayanidhi  Maran",      <------- Name
         15,
         12,
         "Tamil Nadu",      <------- State
         "Chennai Central",
         20,      <------- Total Sessions (Attendance)
         7      <------- Sessions Attended (Attendance)
      ],
      [
         3,
         16,
         "Shri  A.  Raja",      <------- Name
         15,
         12,
         "Tamil Nadu ",      <------- State
         "Nilgiris",
         20,      <------- Total Sessions (Attendance)
         16      <------- Sessions Attended (Attendance)
      ],.....
    ]
}
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
leadersDecoder : Decode.Decoder (List Leader)
leadersDecoder =
    Decode.at [ "data" ] (Decode.list leaderDecoder)


leaderDecoder : Decode.Decoder Leader
leaderDecoder =
    let
        sessionsAttendedDecoder =
            Decode.index 7 Decode.float
                |> Decode.andThen (\total -> attendanceDecoder
                |> Decode.map (\attended -> (attended / total) * 100))
    in
        Decode.map3 Leader
            sessionsAttendedDecoder
            (Decode.index 2 Decode.string)
            (Decode.index 5 Decode.string)

attendanceDecoder : Decode.Decoder Float
attendanceDecoder =
    (Decode.oneOf
        [ Decode.index 8 Decode.float
        , Decode.succeed 0
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Json.Decode.index`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#index) can be used to pull a specific index out of an array with the specified decoder. Couple that with [`andThen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#andThen) and [`map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#map) to do the attendance calculation based on multiple fields:

```elm
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

leaderDecoder : Decoder Leader
leaderDecoder =
    let
        sessionsAttendedDecoder =
            index 7 float
                |> andThen (\total -> index 8 float
                |> map (\attended -> (attended / total) * 100))
    in
        map3 Leader
            sessionsAttendedDecoder
            (index 2 string)
            (index 5 string)
```

Comment: if I wanted to sort the response by the "attendance" key before updating my model, how would I do that ?

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are best left at single, targeted questions. Please open a new question for the sorting question, and include code from your `update` function.

Comment: Not sure if I should be posting this here.. but could you help with my new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205588/chain-http-request-and-merge-json-response-in-elm)