# Chain http request and merge json response in ELM

Tags: json, http, elm

I've succeeded in triggering a simple http request in ELM and decoding the JSON response into an ELM value - [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139316/decode-nested-variable-length-json-in-elm]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139316/decode-nested-variable-length-json-in-elm)

The **problem** I'm facing now-

*How to chain (concurrency preferred) two http requests and merge the json into my new (updated) model. Note - please see the updated Commands.elm*

Package used to access remote data - krisajenkins/remotedata http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/remotedata/4.3.0/RemoteData

Github repo of my code - https://github.com/areai51/my-india-elm

**Previous Working Code -**

*Models.elm*

```
type alias Model =
    { leaders : WebData (List Leader)
    }

initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { leaders = RemoteData.Loading
    }
```

*Main.elm*

```
init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( initialModel, fetchLeaders )
```

*Commands.elm*

```
fetchLeaders : Cmd Msg
fetchLeaders =
    Http.get fetchLeadersUrl leadersDecoder
        |> RemoteData.sendRequest
        |> Cmd.map Msgs.OnFetchLeaders


fetchLeadersUrl : String
fetchLeadersUrl =
    "https://data.gov.in/node/85987/datastore/export/json"
```

*Msgs.elm*

```
type Msg
    = OnFetchLeaders (WebData (List Leader))
```

*Update.elm*

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Msgs.OnFetchLeaders response ->
            ( { model | leaders = response }, Cmd.none )
```

**Updated Code -** *(need help with Commands.elm)*

*Models.elm*

```
type alias Model =
    { lsLeaders : WebData (List Leader)
    , rsLeaders : WebData (List Leader)           <------------- Updated Model
    }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { lsLeaders = RemoteData.Loading
    , rsLeaders = RemoteData.Loading
    }
```

*Main.elm*

```
init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( initialModel, fetchLeaders )
```

*Commands.elm*

```
fetchLeaders : Cmd Msg
fetchLeaders =                                  <-------- How do I call both requests here ? And fire separate msgs
    Http.get fetchLSLeadersUrl lsLeadersDecoder    <----- There will be a different decoder named rsLeadersDecoder
        |> RemoteData.sendRequest
        |> Cmd.map Msgs.OnFetchLSLeaders


fetchLSLeadersUrl : String
fetchLSLeadersUrl =
    "https://data.gov.in/node/85987/datastore/export/json"


fetchRSLeadersUrl : String                     <------------------ New data source
fetchRSLeadersUrl =
    "https://data.gov.in/node/982241/datastore/export/json"
```

*Msgs.elm*

```
type Msg
    = OnFetchLSLeaders (WebData (List Leader))
    | OnFetchRSLeaders (WebData (List Leader))         <-------- New message
```

*Update.elm*

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Msgs.OnFetchLSLeaders response ->
            ( { model | lsLeaders = response }, Cmd.none )

        Msgs.OnFetchRSLeaders response ->                  <--------- New handler
            ( { model | rsLeaders = response }, Cmd.none )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to fire off two concurrent requests is to use `Cmd.batch`:

```elm
init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( initialModel, Cmd.batch [ fetchLSLeaders, fetchRSLeaders ] )
```

There is no guarantee on which request will return first and there is no guarantee that they will both be successful. One could fail while the other succeeds, for example.

You mention that you want to merge the results, but you didn't say how the merge would work, so I'll just assume you want to append the lists of leaders together in one list, and it will be useful to your application if you had only to deal with a single `RemoteData` value rather than multiple.

You can merge multiple `RemoteData` values together with a custom function using `map` and `andMap`.

```
mergeLeaders : WebData (List Leader) -> WebData (List Leader) -> WebData (List Leader)
mergeLeaders a b =
    RemoteData.map List.append a
        |> RemoteData.andMap b
```

Notice that I'm using `List.append` there. That can really be any function that takes two lists and merges them however you please.

If you prefer an applicative style of programming, the above could be translated to the following infix version:

```
import RemoteData.Infix exposing (..)

mergeLeaders2 : WebData (List Leader) -> WebData (List Leader) -> WebData (List Leader)
mergeLeaders2 a b =
    List.append <$> a <*> b
```

According to the documentation on [`andMap`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/remotedata/4.3.0/RemoteData#andMap) (which uses a result tuple rather than an appended list in its example):

> The final tuple succeeds only if all its children succeeded. It is still Loading if any of its children are still Loading. And if any child fails, the error is the leftmost Failure value.